# SQL Server renames tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using a SQL Server from my hosting provider and the strangest things happen. The server sometimes renames my tables, to the english word - from swedish, and then uses that table instead of the one i have declared in my code first, even though its not even the same name? I use code-first Entity Framework, has anyone experienced this?

I.e: `Personer`, it renamed to People !

Comment: SQL Server isn't renaming your tables.  I'm guessing your deployment strategy is.  Is your entity called Person?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF uses an English-based pluralization/singularization system that might get in your way here.

Since it sees `Person`, it will change that table name to `People` which is the proper English plural for `Person`.

You can disable that "feature" with this code in `OnModelCreating` method:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

Comment: Thank you, this really came as a surprise, I guess Entity Framework can be too helpful sometimes :)

Comment: @user3581054: yes, it does get a bit "funny" at times with non-English table names (I'm using German names - and those "pluralizations" that EF comes up with are hilarious). Good thing it can be turned off easily :-)